# An ugly anime girl becomes a beauty

Tags: story-identification, anime

Through a fortuitous event, I have found a video clip that I haven't been able to find for 15 years. Even with the name "Beauty shower pt1" it will not appear in YouTube or Google search.

The video clip is about a large woman with the shape of a sumo wrestler who works as a sit-in companion at a table. She is obviously unhappy with her body shape. One day a fortune teller sells her a pair of pantyhose's which removes all the unnecessary hair on her body and makes her skin look wonderful. It helps, but it's not enough. The next day the fortune teller sells her a balloon, which she happily pays for without any hesitation. After working hard to blow it up into a humanoid shape, the woman shapes the balloon from a fat pudgy shape into a Barbie-doll shape, and her body is transformed. Now when she goes to work all the men want to sit with her at her table. Unfortunately the clip ends there.

I know that there's a subtitled version in English and a part two but I can't find them; I don't know the name either. I can't read the Japanese script. Can anyone possibly identify this anime or translate the name?

Comment: Here's part two: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i-BQnNrghpo

Comment: Thankyou. Although it's pretty clear that Youtube is preventing me from searching out this video manually. I'd still like to know where this cartoon is from. It's clearly from the 1990s or even earlier. If anyone has any information on what it is or where we can find the English Sub version it would be a great help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is from a long-running anthology series called [Shuukan Storyland](https://myanimelist.net/anime/13551/Shuukan_Storyland?suggestion=) that ran from 1999 to 2001, specifically the recurring segment "Nazo no Rouba" (the mysterious old lady), and even more specifically the episode "Beauty Shower". The segment has a lengthy article on the [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%AC%8E%E3%81%AE%E8%80%81%E5%A9%86).

As the article describes, the series has the old lady selling magical items to a variety of people who mostly go overboard in their use, leading to their downfall - in this episode, the okama (cross-dresser) Charlotte uses the magical items to become the top hostess at the bar, but finally uses a "beauty shower" to lighten her skin that turns her into a walking skeleton.

I couldn't find any evidence of the series having been officially subbed or dubbed into English, but there may be some fansubs floating around in some random corner of the internet.

Comment: As a bit of an aside to the actual answer, in trying to find this series I first searched for the name of the okama bar and it turned out to be the name of a completely unrelated horror manga, which took me down quite the rabbit hole before I realised it wasn't leading anywhere.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer.